# SQLite Blob not coverting to string error

Tags: android, sqlite

This post is a continuance of my previous question about saving an image to SQLite. I am getting cannot convert Blob to String error at FoodList activity startup with crash. I am using SQLite Helper and an adapter. My Main Activity code is as follows:

```
public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 999;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();

    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "FoodDB.sqlite", null, 1);

    sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD (name TEXT, price TEXT, image BLOB)");

    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY
            );
        }
    });

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                        edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
                        imageViewToByte(imageView)

                );
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entry Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                edtName.setText("");
                edtPrice.setText("");
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FoodList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY) {
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //return;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private void init() {
     edtName = findViewById(R.id.edtName);
     edtPrice = findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
     btnChoose = findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
     btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
     btnList = findViewById(R.id.btnList);
     imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

}
```

}

Then my SQLite Helper class is as follows:

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);


}
public void queryData(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL(sql);
}

public void insertData(String name, String price, byte[] image) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO FOOD VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString(1, name);
    statement.bindString(2, price); 
    statement.bindBlob(3, image);

    statement.executeInsert();
}
public Cursor getData(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    return database.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
```

}

My food list adapter code is this:

```
public class FoodListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<Food> foodsList;

public FoodListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Food> foodsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.foodsList = foodsList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return foodsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return foodsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName, txtPrice;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
        row.setTag(holder);

    }
    else  {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Food food = foodsList.get(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(food.getName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(food.getPrice());

    byte[] foodImage = food.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodImage, 0, foodImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    return row;
}
```

}

I also have a class called Food that code is also as follows:

```
public class Food {

private String name;
private String price;
private byte[] image;

public Food(String name, String price, byte[] image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = image;

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

And last but not least, here is the code for the activity that crashes upon initialization FoodList:

```
public class FoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Food> list;
FoodListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_list_activity);

    gridView =  findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new FoodListAdapter(this, R.layout.food_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Food(name, price, image));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

I have no clue what is causing this error. hopefully someone can shed some light on my issue...

Comment: column indexes are zero-based ... also it is no safe to use `select * ...` with hard-coded  column indexes

Comment: I'm new to SQLite. Do you know an alternative? and do you think this could be what is causing this error?

Comment: `select column0, column1 ...` or use proper Cursor method to get index by name ... **and the error is because indexes are zero-based** not one-based (as parameters binding are)

Comment: Will apply changes this afternoon. thanks for the help. makes sense. will get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");`

Will return a Cursor that has 3 columns, **name**, **price** and **image** as such you will have columns with offsets **0** (***name***), **1** (***price***) and **2** (***image***).

Therefore, **`getString(2)`** is trying to get the image column which is a BLOB, but as a **String**, hence the error trying to convert the BLOB to a String.

*If it hand't of failed then you would have got another failure with an index error with `getBlob(3)` as there is no column with an offset of 3.*

It is best to not use offsets normally, but rather use the **`getColumnIndex(column_name)`** method which returns the column offset(index) according to the given column name.

As such, you could use the following, which would fix the issue :-

```
    String name = cursor.getString(getColumnIndex("name"));
    String price = cursor.getString(getColumnIndex("price"));
    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(getColumnIndex("image"));
```

Comment: Awesome , that was it!!

Comment: String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            String price = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("price"));
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));

Comment: @Devsolutionsbeyond, np. It would be good if you could mark answers as being answers if they answer your questions and upvote comments and answers as being helpful it they are.

Comment: I did ..but because my reputation is under 15 it wont publicaly show is what the dialog tells me...i am very grateful though. thank you

Comment: was clicking wrong thing sry was trying to give you reputation points as well